# Flask-restful, marshal_with + nested data

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have been stuck on this for a while now. My problem is I need to be able to use marshal_with and validate on nested fields coming from a POST. My test looks like this:

```
def test_user_can_apply_with_multiple_dogs(self):

    data = {
        # User data
        'registration_type': "guest",
        'first_name': 'Alex',
        'last_name': 'Daro',
        'phone_number': '805-910-9198',
        'street': '13950 NW Passage',
        'street2': '#208',
        'city': 'Marina del Rey',
        'state': 'CA',
        'zipcode': '90292',
        'photo': 'test_image.png',
        'how_did_you_hear': 0,
        #Dog data
        'pets': [
            {
                'dog_photo': "dog.png",
                'name': 'Genghis Khan',
                'breed': 'Shih Tzu',
                'age': 'Puppy',
                'size': 'Small',
            },
            {
                'dog_photo': "dog2.png",
                'name': 'Archibald',
                'breed': 'Great Dane',
                'age': 'Adult',
                'size': 'Extra Large',
            },
        ]
    }

    resp = self.client.post('/profile/registration', data=json.dumps(data))
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

and my endpoint class looks like this:

```
nested_fields = {
    'dog_photo': fields.String,
    'name': fields.String,
    'breed': fields.String,
    'age': fields.String, 
    'size': fields.String, 
}

profile_fields = {
    # 'user_email':fields.String,
    'token': fields.String,
    'registration_type': fields.String,
    'first_name': fields.String,
    'last_name': fields.String,
    'phone_number': fields.String,
    'street': fields.String,
    'street2': fields.String,
    'city': fields.String,
    'state': fields.String,
    'zipcode': fields.Integer,
    'photo': fields.String,
    'how_did_you_hear': fields.String,
    #Dog data
    'pets': fields.Nested(nested_fields)

}
class GuestProfile(Resource):
    @marshal_with(profile_fields)
    def post(self):
        # User data
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('registration_type', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('first_name', type=str, required=True, help="First Name cannot be blank.")
        parser.add_argument('last_name', type=str, required=True, help="Last Name cannot be blank.")
        parser.add_argument('phone_number', type=str, required=True, help="Phone Number cannot be blank.")
        parser.add_argument('street', type=str, required=True, help="Street cannot be blank.")
        parser.add_argument('street2', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('city', type=str, required=True, help="City cannot be blank.")
        parser.add_argument('state', type=str, required=True, help="State cannot be blank.")
        parser.add_argument('zipcode', type=str, required=True, help="Zipcode cannot be blank.")
        parser.add_argument('photo', type=str, required=True, help="Please select a photo.")
        parser.add_argument('how_did_you_hear', type=str, required=True, help="How did you hear about us cannot be "
                                                                              "blank.")
        parser.add_argument('pets', type=str)
        kwargs = parser.parse_args()
        print kwargs, "KWWW"
```

kwargs['pet'] always comes in as `None`. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You should stop using `type=str`. I gather by the print statement that you use python 2 and thus your parser will not be able to handle unicode. If you remove the `type` parameter completely, the default type will be a unicode string.

Comment: @Josh thank you for the comment, that makes sense but it didn't seem to help. Do you know of any examples/documentation that has an example of using marshal_with/reqparse with a nested list of objects?

Comment: You can also clean up the code by not instantiating a new `RequestParser` for each request. It's totally fine to put those at the module level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's an example in the docs of how to make a custom parser type.](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.3/intermediate-usage.html#full-parameter-parsing-example)

Basically, you define a function that:

- Takes the raw value of the argument pulled from the request
- Raises `ValueError` if parsing or validation fails
- Returns the argument if validation suceeds

Basic example related to your question:

```python
def pet_list_parser(pets):
    if type(pets) != list:
        raise ValueError('Expected a list!')

    # Do your validation of the pet objects here. For example:
    for pet in pets:
        if 'name' not in pet:
            raise ValueError('Pet name is required')

        # Also do any conversion of data types here
        pet['name'] = pet['name'].capitalize()

    return pets

parser = RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('pets', type=pet_list_parser)
```

As you might guess, this gets klunky and annoying rather quickly. The request parsing in Flask-RESTful isn't designed to handle nested data. It works very well for querystring arguments, headers, basic JSON, etc. and can be configured to handle nested data. However if you are going to do this a lot, save yourself some pain down the road and look into a marshalling library like [Marshmallow](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: one problem with my setup. The pets arg coming into pet_list_parser is coming in as a dictionary, not a list. Does my `profile_fields` look correct to you, specifically the `'pets': fields.Nested(nested_fields)` line?

Comment: See @junnytony's suggestion to use `'pets': fields.List(fields.Nested(nested_fields))` (you did not explicitly say in your code that you needed a list of objects)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing 'Content-Type' header and also an `action='append'` for your pets argument as described [here](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reqparse.html#multiple-values-lists).

I tested your code above with just adding the 'Content-Type' and action as prescribed and it works in both Python 2.7 and 3.

Now the issue is it returns a list of strings since you specified your pets argument as `type=str`. In order to get a list of dicts, you'll have to write a custom parser type (as @Josh rightly pointed out). See example below:

Ex.

```
def pet_parser(pet):
    # You can do other things here too as suggested in @Josh's repsonse
    return pet
```

In the Resource:

```
parser.add_argument('pets', type=pet_parser, action='append')
```

and in your test function:

```
headers = [('Content-Type', 'application/json')]
self.client.post('url', data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: thanks @junnytony for the reply although, that didn't seem to help. Do you know of any examples/documentation that has an example of using marshal_with/reqparse with a nested list of objects?

Comment: @DirkDigler. In what way did this not help? If you're more specific, I may be able to provide an answer that helps you better. See my edits above.

Comment: see @Josh's answer below. Seems like your edits were more of what I was looking for.

Comment: one problem with my setup. The pets arg coming into pet_list_parser is coming in as a dictionary, not a list. Does my `profile_fields` look correct to you, specifically the `'pets': fields.Nested(nested_fields)` line?

Comment: I didn't quite follow your first comment. To your question, If you're expecting to return a list of pets then you should have `'pets': fields.List(fields.Nested(nested_fields))`

Comment: @junnytony you should **not** use `json.loads` inside a custom validator unless you expect the argument to contain a json encoded string. By the time the input gets to this validator, the request's json has already been decoded and is passed to the validators and parsers as a `dict` or `list`.

Comment: @Josh, you're very right. I completely missed that. Edited above. Thanks for pointing that out.